# Receiving odd error message in PS script

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a PowerShell script that goes out grabs the currently logged in user on a remote computer and gets the total size of their local profile C:\users\USERNAME\documents, pictures, music, etc.  I have confirmed that the remote computer is online and the user is logged in.  While the script is working, in the sense that it gets the folder size, it returns this message:

```
Get-WmiObject : Invalid parameter
At C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\get_folder_size.ps1:4 char:9
+ $user = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $system | Se ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\get_folder_size.ps1:5 char:1
+ $pos = $user.IndexOf("\")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\get_folder_size.ps1:6 char:1
+ $user = $user.Substring($pos+1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I'm confused because if I'm reading the message correctly it shouldn't be able to grab the username thus not get the correct folder and the size.

Here is the code that I'm running

```
foreach ($system in Get-Content "C:\net_view.txt")
{
    $colItems = 0
    $user = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $system |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName
    $pos  = $user.IndexOf("\")
    $user = $user.Substring($pos+1)

    $path = $system +"\c$\users\" + $user

    $colItems = (Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
                Measure-Object -property length -sum)
    "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"

    Add-Content C:\users\administrator\desktop\profile_size.txt ($colItems.sum / 1MB)
    Add-Content C:\users\administrator\desktop\profile_size.txt $system
}
```

Comment: Well, presumably it's getting the size of the wrong folder (e.g. the script's local folder). Or it's the only user account and it's getting c:\users\* and the size is approximately right. Or you set the username somewhere else, or some other variable (a typo of the variable name?) mistakenly and are using that. Without seeing your code, all we can do is guess. Edit your question and post the code in it?

Comment: Check the value of `$system` at the time the error occurs. Make sure it is what you think it is.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, I was able to verify that the $system variable is returning the correct values.  Any other points to check?